# How to trigger different functions when I click the same element?

Tags: javascript, click

```
<div class="slide_button_wrapper left first" ><p class="text">Text1</p></div>
<div class="slide_button_wrapper right first" ><p class="text">Text2</p></div>
<div class="slide_button_wrapper left second"><p class="text">Text3</p></div>
<div class="slide_button_wrapper right second" ><p class="text">Text4</p></div>
<div class="slide_button_wrapper left third" ><p class="text">Text5</p></div>
```

What I'm trying to do is when I click Text1, then the color of Text1 will become red, when I click another one, say Text3, then the color of Text3 will become blue, but Text1 will still be red, then when I click the third time on any div, nothing should be happening. Don't know how to do this, thanks in advance!

Comment: vanilla javascript or jquery?

Comment: you can have a global variable for click count whose value you can check on every click if it is not at it's limit then allow click and increment the count   and if it reaches it's limit do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind `click` event handler for your `divs` and use `css()` method in order to `get/set` the colour of your `div`.

```js
var colors=['red','blue'];
var i=0;
$('div').click(function(){
    if($(this).css('background-color')=='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)' && i<colors.length)
      $(this).css('background-color',colors[i++]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide_button_wrapper left first" ><p class="text">Text1</p></div>
<div class="slide_button_wrapper right first" ><p class="text">Text2</p></div>
<div class="slide_button_wrapper left second"><p class="text">Text3</p></div>
<div class="slide_button_wrapper right second" ><p class="text">Text4</p></div>

<div class="slide_button_wrapper left third" ><p class="text">Text5</p></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```js
var colors = ['red', 'blue'];
colors = colors.reverse();

var texts = document.querySelectorAll('.text');
texts.forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (colors.length > 0) {
      var color = colors.pop();
      element.style.color = color;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<span class="text">TEXT</span>
<span class="text">TEXT</span>
<span class="text">TEXT</span>
<span class="text">TEXT</span>
<span class="text">TEXT</span>
<span class="text">TEXT</span>
<span class="text">TEXT</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="text" onclick="myFunction()">Text.</p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
}
</script>
```

UPDATE= you need to change class for id, or just add `id="text"` to call the object

Answer (score 0):

If you meant that each element has its own color then I suggest adding a `data-attribute` to the elements, let's say `data-color`, and change the color according to its value.

For example:

```
<div class="slide_button_wrapper left first" ><p class="text" data-color="red">Text1</p></div>
<div class="slide_button_wrapper right first" ><p class="text" data-color="blue">Text2</p></div>
```

Pure JavaScript:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.text');
for(var z = 0; z < elements.length; z++) {
    var elem = elements[z];
    elem.onclick = function() {
        var color = this.getAttribute("data-color");
        this.style.color = color;
        return false;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code before the end of your `</body>` tag.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var counter = 0;
        $('.text').on('click', function() {
            counter++;
            if(counter < 3)
            {
                if($(this).text() == 'Text1')
                    $(this).css("color", "red");
                else
                    $(this).css("color", "blue");
            }
        });    
    });
</script>
```

Code explaination follows:

Step 1: We're importing Jquery library first, because it gives more flexibility in writing javascript code.

Step 2: Declaring a global `counter`variable and initializing it to `0`.

Step 3: Binding a function to the click event for elements with class `text`.

Step 4: Checking if `counter < 3`. If it is not then do nothing otherwise check if clicked element was 'Text1' then change it's color to 'red' otherwise change color to 'blue'.

Your description was a little vague so only thing I came up was this. You can change this code to your requirements now.